# Почему GameObject.FindWithTag возвращает null?

Tags: c#, unity3d

На сцене есть 2 камеры: главная и вторая неактивная с тэгом "my tag". Почему при использовании camera_2 = GameObject.FindWithTag("my tag"); вторая камера не находится, а возвращается null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Увы, данный метод не умеет искать выключенные объекты. Как вариант - оставить объект включенным на момент запуска и выключить его сразу после нахождения по тэгу.

```
camera_2 = GameObject.FindWithTag("my tag");
camera_2.SetActive(false);
```

Однако, поиск по тэгу - это очень плохая идея с точки зрения производительности :) возможно, стоит подумать о какой-то иной реализации?